# rosjava dependencies

Tags: ros, rosjava, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the version of rosjava before using Gradle, Java files for all messages in packages depended on in manifest.xml would be created in ~/.ros/rosjava.  I am trying to convert an old package to use the new Gradle build system but I get the following errors for all of my imports:

error: package org.ros.message.geometry_msgs does not exist

Also ~/.ros/rosjava is not created.  Is there something extra I need to do with Gradle to make Java files created for these non-rosjava packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49273/rosjava-dependencies/) by [Rorry_Brenner](https://answers.ros.org/users/1319/rorry_brenner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow the installation and build instructions here:

http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html

You have not built and installed rosjava_messages.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0